# Desactivar un Scheduled Service en un proyecto Spring Boot durante un Integration Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Tengo un servicio que se encarga de hacer unas llamadas a un método cada X segundos .

```
@Service
public class TService {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TService.class);



@Autowired
private Integration Integration;

private boolean enabled = true;

private static final TService INSTANCE = new TService();

public static final TService getInstance() {
    return TService.INSTANCE;
}


@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
public void exec() {
    try {
        if (this.enabled) {
            final Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            this.Integration.make(now);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        TService.LOGGER.warn("Exception: ", e);
    }
}

public void disable() {
    this.enabled = false;
    LOGGER.info("TService disabled");
}

public void enable() {
    this.enabled = true;
    LOGGER.info("TService enabled");
}
}
```

El servicio funciona perfectamente y realiza su función. El tema es que cuando realizo unos test para probar el código establezco la variable enabled de TService a false y así poder tener apagado el servicio de esta manera:

```
public class Test1 {

public Test1() {
    super();
}

@Before
public void before() {
    TService.getInstance().disable();
}

@After
public void after() {
    TService.getInstance().enable();
}

@Test
public void successfulFlow() throws Exception {
    SuccessfulFlowTest.getInstance().run(arg1, arg2);
}

@Test
public void failureFlow() throws Exception {
    CreationeFailureTest.getInstance().run(arg1, arg2);
}
}
```

El servicio se desactiva, pero hay momentos que el servicio realiza sus tareas cuando establezco a false el valor de enabled. Al tratarse de un proyecto de spring creo que en algún momento internamente (al estar inyectada la dependencia del servicio) spring la establece a true o algo del estilo. 
¿Alguna pauta para manejar este tipo de situaciones?

Comment: La establece a true porque es una variable global que estás iniciando a nivel de clase y, cada test, levanta una nueva instancia de ese bean por lo que vuelve a valer true, lo que no entiendo es, si lo que quieres es desactivar el servicio en los test... por qué simplemente no testeas ese servicio?

Comment: El fin de estos test no es probar el servicio es que a la hora de lanzar los test lo que hace el servicio no lo haga. Para así yo poder hacer lo que hace pero de manera manual. Entonces claro al no detenerse el servicio se solapa lo que me hace el servicio con lo que yo meto a pelo.  Como podría hacer que se genera una unica instancia de la clase del servicio??

Comment: Puedes desactivar el servicio en función de una variable de configuración con la etiqueta '@ConditionalOnProperty por ejemplo pero no entiendo muy bien porque quieres llamar al servicio en un test si no quieres "hacer lo que hace el servicio", no estoy seguro de si entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: Si dependiese del servicio llevar a cabo los test me tardaría horas, En cambio si desactivo el servicio y voy haciendo lo yo directamente en los test la ejecucion se reduce considerablemente. El problema con este plantamiento es que al no tener el servicio apagado se solapa lo que hace el servicio con lo que yo le mando.

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo: quieres hacer un test unitario y ese servicio sólo te genera ruido, con lo que quieres desactivarlo únicamente cuando estás haciendo tests. ¿Es eso?

Comment: Si eso es, lo único distinto que es un test de integración. Pero lo mismo da que da lo mismo

Comment: Es posible utilizar [mocks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) en integration tests para simular ciertas condiciones. Has intentado "mockear" este servicio?

Comment: Lo probare @cavpollo el tema es que actualmente he probado a tener dos properties y cargar el valor segun mi necesidad. Y ahora por cada clase con @ Test me lanza la aplicacion de nuevo y me da errores con el puerto ya que no esta libre. He probado con @ EnableScheduling pero no estoy viendo completamente su necesidad. Probare lo que me comentas